# Can I ignore the auto increment id when I enter the data into database using java?

Tags: java, mysql, xampp

How can I ignore auto increment of ID when I insert data in Java?

```
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
    pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into jeff(j_fname,j_lname,j_mail,j_password) values(?,?,?,?)");
    pst.setString(1, namef);
    pst.setString(2, namel);
    pst.setString(3,maila);
    pst.setString(4,pass);
    pst.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: You can test it by yourself and will find the answer

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot turn it off on that `ID` column?

Comment: I found out thanks

Answer (score 0):

[refer here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMDcf.png)Auto increment of ID is enabled in table structure. Please check database table structure.

Comment: I did that.I just wanted to know that I can ignore that auto increment part and only add values to the other columns

Comment: Then just untick AI column in table structure as well as your domain class.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the id column in your insert statement!
If you have removed the auto increment property from the column you must add id column in the  insert statement.